# Javascript that reads RSS in safari?

Tags: javascript, rss

I've searched around, and there doesn't seem to be a way to read remote RSS files via javascript... specifically in safari

This is more or less what i'm trying to do...

I've tried

```
xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
```

or

```
xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
```

and then

```
xmlDoc.load('http://localhost/drupal/feed');
```

This is where it breaks though.

Answer (score 1):

The first result for "read rss with javascript" in Google is [this article](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1672), which describes exactly what you intend to do (in a cross-browser way, no less).

The reason the code you pasted above doesn't work is that you're using `ActiveXObject`, which Safari doesn't use. Active X objects are an Internet Explorer-only thing. Safari, Firefox, Opera, and other standards-compliant browsers use `XMLHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to roll your own give [this](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/) a look. It's Google's AJAX Feed lib.  I had to load up a blog for a client a few months back and this saved me quite a bit of time.